# STS: How to remove hot swapping

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I'm analyzing "Serving Web Content" guide and I would like to make some changes. However, to apply them, I need to restart the server every time. I've read the hot swapping should be enable to solve this, but I wasn't successful. Is there an easy way to enable hot swapping on Spring Tool Suite?

Thank you

**EDIT 1:**

[image: Package Explorer]

Comment: You need to add `devtools` dependency in `pom.xml` file, and turn on `Build Automatically` option in `Project` menu

Comment: @ELITE Hi, they are enabled. The fact is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I cannot explain why (e.g. I change a file extension and then I get an error 404 on the browser)

Comment: where are your web contents. in class path resources or anywhere else??

Comment: @ELITE Please see EDIT 1. This is a Spring example.

Comment: you can use `spring.resources.static-locations=file:gui` property in `application.properties` to get static contents from `gui` folder which is placed in project folder and then try once.